# Program does not contain a static Main method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning C# and trying to understand the basics.

Recently I made an example like this:

```
namespace Classes
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public void Introduce(string to)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi {0}, I am {1}", to, Name);
        }
    }
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person();
            person.Name = "Alex";
            person.Introduce("John");
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine without any error, but I've got some problems with the `static void Main(string[] args)` part.

I tried changing `static` here to `public` but it returns this error:

`Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

And unfortunately I can't understand, why `static` cannot be changed to `public` here!

I know this question might sounds newbie specially for pros but please help me out with this cause I have had googled also but couldn't solve my problem...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Well, it *does* need to be static... it *doesn't* need to be public, unless the OP has some particular reason for that which we don't know.

Comment: You will learn soon what static and public mean. They are different concepts. Main is the method  that starts your program to run. The word static means that there cannot be copies of main. The word public means the method is accessible from any  class, though a number of conditions apply). You do not need that here.. This is a very much simplified explanation. Keep learning and you will soon get used to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` method is what your computer(*) will look for when it tries to execute code written in C#. Citing Microsoft I might add that "`Main` must be `static` and it need not be `public`." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/).

If you are new to programming, just use what [Eldshe has mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816140/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method/65816223#65816223):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

And then simply ignore what it means.

(*) apparently a simplification

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```